# Angular: Inherited method extend in the child controller scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, inheritance, controller

I've got a problem that is getting into my nerves regarding some methods extending in an angular child controller. My primary goal is to inherit all the public /$scope/ variables and methods from the parent controller into the child one, but extend some specific functions with more logic. So this is what I have in general:

```
var app = angular.module("conrollersInheritance", []);

app.controller("parentController", [
    "$scope",
    function ($scope) {
        /* PRIVATE */
        var privateVar1 = "private variable 1";
        var privateVar2 = "private variable 2";

        // ...Some other private stuff here...

        /* PUBLIC */
        $scope.publicVar1 = "public variable 1";
        $scope.publicVar2 = "public variable 2";

        $scope.showVars = function () {
            console.log("PRIVATE: ", privateVar1, privateVar2);
            console.log("PUBLIC: ", $scope.publicVar1, $scope.publicVar2);
        };

        // ...Some other public stuff here...
    }
]);

app.controller("childController", [
    "$scope", "$controller",
    function ($scope, $controller) {
        $controller("parentController", { $scope: $scope });

        $scope.showVars = function () {
            alert("child scope");
            // ???Here I want to execute the inherited method from the `parentController`
        };
    }
]);
```

So basically, the `childController` inherits all the `$scope` data from the `parentController` which is fine, but I cannot seem to extend the functionality inherited, but always override it. I tried different approaches to solve the problem, because I saw from the Angular docs that the `$controller` service should return the instance / https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$controller /, but in my case it always returns an empty contructor object. SO when I try to do something like this into the `childController`:

```
var parentController = $controller( "parentController", { $scope: $scope } );
```

I am always getting an emtpy object for the `parentConroller` variable and I cannot use anything inherited from there. Tried to use the viewmodel declaration inside the `childController` with something like this:

```
var vm = this;
$controller( "parentController", { vm: $scope } );
angular.extend( $scope, vm );
```

but also seems not to be the right decisions as it throws an error when trying to extend the scope and I cannot do anything like this as well:

```
$scope.showVars = function() {
    alert( "child scope" );
    vm.showVars();
};
```

So, I'm kind of stuck how can I do this. I read a lot of tutorials claiming that above methods should work, but it doesn't look like this in my case. So, any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: `$scope.$parent.showVars()`?

Comment: hmmm, haven't thought about that this could happen. I will check it up now... probably this will help me fix that thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to prototypical inheritance, your child controller inherits all parent's properties/methods from the `$scope` by default, if your controllers are nested.

You can nest controllers by either using `ui-router` and defining a child state

```
.state('route', {
    controller: 'ParentController',
    // the rest of the route config
})

.state('route.child', {
    controller: 'ChildController',
    // the rest of the route config
})
```

or by nesting them in the template

```
<div ng-controller="ParentController">
    <div ng-controller="ChildController">
        <!-- the rest of your template -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Then you can simply extend your `ParentController` method like this:

```
$scope.showVars = () => {
    $scope.$parent.showVars();
    // your other logic
};
```

That will create a a `showVars` method on your `ChildController`'s `$scope` which will be used by default by your template instead of the one inherited fro mthe `ParentController`.

Comment: That looks great. I'm actually using the `ui-router` to create states, but for each state I am assigning either a custom controller or `ParentController`. And if I want to use any functionality from `ParentController` into the custom one, I use `$controller` provider to extend it's `$scope`. But then accessing the `ParentController` scope seems impossible, as `$scope.$parent` doesn't consist with it's methods and variables. Do I need to make changes on  states and make all of them nested to a single main state that has the `ParentController` assigned?

Comment: I believe the best practice would be to assign one controller per state. If you have child state, its controller will automatically inherit everything from the controller of its parent state.